# Roots of sum of two polynomials, with added assumption

Tags: polynomials

Suppose I have two polynomials

$$ P(x) = a_0 + a_1x+ ... + a_n x^n$$
$$ Q(x) = b_0 + b_1x+ ... + b_n x^n$$
where:

- all coefficients are real;
- $a_n, b_n$ are negative;
- $a_i, b_i$ are positive for any $0 \leq i < n$;
- $a_0 + ... + a_{n-1} > |a_n|$;
- $b_0 + ... + b_{n-1} > |b_n|$.

It is fairly straight forward to show that any such polynomial has a unique positive root (and if you want to be fancy, you can use Decartes' Rule of Signs to prove that).

--> Suppose I know this unique positive roots for both $P$ and $Q$. How can I compute the unique positive root of $P + Q$?

- If it is easier, how can I compute any of the other roots?
- If it is easier, I can assume $a_0 = a_1 = ... = a_{n-1}$ and $b_0 = b_1 = ... = b_{n-1}$.

Comment: Do you have solutions for some small cases such as $n=2$?

Comment: @ZachTeitler You mean other than just using a straight forward formula? no.